# how to make BERT predict new token

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, huggingface-tokenizers

**my problem looks like this:**

```
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
model = BertForMaskedLM.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
fill_mask_pipeline_pre = pipeline("fill-mask", model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer)
sentence_test = "Olaf is the chancellor of germany. [MASK] is the chancellor of germany."
prediction = fill_mask_pipeline_pre(sentence_test)[:3]
```

--> the 1st prediction is "Olaf", which is the result I wanted.

However, if sentence_test is this:

```
sentence_test = "Scholz is the chancellor of germany. [MASK] is the chancellor of germany."
```

... I want the prediction to be "Scholz".

Unfortunately this in never predicted, because BERT does not know the word Scholz.
BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased') turns Scholz into "sc" and  "##holz" .

**Is there a way how the new token can be predicted?
**

I tried adding the token to the tokenizer, but it still isn't predicted.

I also fine- tuned the model on text that contains the word "Scholz" a lot after adding the new word to the tokenizer, but it does not work either.

Comment: BERT is limited to predicting only the same number of MASK tokens. However, you can try T5 which can predict a span of mask inputs and it fits your goal better. Note that T5 is in the encoder-decoder framework which is different from encoder-only BERT.

Comment: https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_doc/t5